# Apache/PHP: Force execution of signed code only (or known MD5)

Tags: php, apache, security, code-signing

Just thought about hardening our Apache/PHP server installations and pondering about a general approach. Is it possible to create a configuration in that php code is only then executed, when it is "signed" or the hash sum (e.g. MD5) is known?

Has anyone a suggestion?

Comment: This is actually a great idea for an Apache module, but I think Apache (or any other server I know of) cannot currently do this. Some problems are obviously key management for the signing keys (how and where to store signing keys and also file signatures) and performance (Apache would need to check signatures on each request, that's very computationally intensive). But I really like the idea. (Also MD5 is not suitable for this, but that's just a technical detail.)

Comment: @GaborLengyel i think that should rather be a PHP-module. apart from being usable with NGINX or CLI (or forbid - IIS), too, it could be integrated with the OPCache-system to alleviate performance problems - a signature check is only executed when the cache gets renewed, and only valid code gets loaded in the cache. a simple makeshift-tool of the logic could be implemented via the [auto_prepend](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive

Comment: Well you can encrypt your php code using ioncube loaders (www.ioncube.com/). It prevents unauthorized update of php code. It is also possible to write a custom php script that compares the current hash of a php page with a stored hash that is known to be valid.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend ionCube or [any other code obfuscation techniques](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/753.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Just a head's up: I wouldn't recommend MD5 here, at all.

That being said, [PHP Archives (a.k.a. Phar)](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php) support code-signing through OpenSSL. This is used in [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/releases/tag/v2.0.11) (see: `random_compat.phar` and `random_compat.phar.pubkey`; the `.asc` file is a GPG signature of the `.pubkey` file).

The code we use to generate signed Phars is located [here](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/blob/0cfdb481b6b1d44bc9186f8cd19cdaf18be0e59e/other/build_phar.php#L9-L57).