# PHP: Prevent Core changes with 3rd party code

Tags: php, security, plugins

I'm starting to develop something (self-hosted - each user installs it on their server - probably a shared server) that allows users to upload other's code (plugins).

One problem that I'm worried about is plugins changing Core files.

The flow of the application is something like this:

```
index.php 
  > Core() 
    > (do stuff) 
    > load/execute plugins <- may have code to replace a Core file 
    > (do stuff) 
    > exit
```

I'm trying to limit plugins access to either *the files* or *php functions*.
It would be great if plugins were only allowed to use Core classes/methods.

Because it is self-hosted (and maybe used by someone who is not a developer) I can't control the *system*, *apache.conf* or *php.ini*. I can only create .htaccess files.

**Solutions I though about:**

~ Using token_get_all() on *.php files (during installation of the plugin) and check if there is any use of functions like *chgrp*, *chmod*, *chown*, *copy*, etc. But this is not ideal, and I am sure I would miss some functions.

**Other solutions (from comments):**

x Changing folder permissions - Can do through php, but so can plugins and the Core can't update itself

x Editing php.ini to prevent usage of functions - Can't. No access to php.ini.

x Using *[snuffleupagus](https://github.com/nbs-system/snuffleupagus)* package - Can't. It's a php extension.

Comment: Server permissions. Se the Core directory to read and execute only, even by the owner. Edit php.ini to prevent usage of dangerous functions like exec() and system(). There is a PHP package that limits where and by who the system functions are allowed.

Comment: I have some questions/problems with your suggestion:

If I set permissions: how to update core, if files can't be written? will plugins be able to change permissions? (using chmod)

Can't edit php.ini because it's self-hosted, can't change apache/php.ini settings, only .htaccess but "disable_functions" doesn't work in .htaccess, also nginx support would be cool

PHP package that limits use of system functions - what package? This looks like what I am looking for, but it can't be an extension

this project will be a zip file - something like Wordpress - so there's not much I can control

Comment: To update core use a system user that would have permissions to write to the given dir. Remember *nix systems permissions are Global-Group-User. Some users CAN do an action other can not. As got php.ini, if it is self-hosted you should have access to everything. Indeed the system functions disable is a php.ini setting. Let me see if I can find the package....here it is: https://github.com/nbs-system/snuffleupagus

Comment: What I mean with self-hosted is that each user installs it in their own system, and most of the time they are not developers, and use shared-hosting accounts. Because of that I really don't have control over the permissions of users, what user is used or php.ini access. The package you suggested is a php extension that I can't use. Sorry if I wasn't clear with the "self-hosted"

Comment: Ah, that clears things up a bit. As per your statement of ` each user installs it in their own system`, this means there is no way to prevent a user from altering Core files. Since the user has access to the machine and the files therein, AFAIK there is no way to 100% prevent alterations.

Comment: Sorry again. I don't want to prevent the user from changing core files, I want to prevent plugins they install from changing core files. What I want is to protect the user, because they may install malicious plugins without even knowing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One problem that I'm worried about is plugins changing Core files.

Ship your Core files as a [signed PHP Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48012442/2224584).

> I'm trying to limit plugins access to either the files or php functions. It would be great if plugins were only allowed to use Core classes/methods.

That's a very challenging problem to solve, and is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer. At a minimum, you need to make sure that the server bootstrapping hits your framework (which works out well if you're using a signed .phar rather than a mutable .php file).

However, beyond that, you cannot stop plugins from calling PHP functions in the standard library. An alternative approach may be to build a Template engine (e.g. like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/)) and only let plugins be written in your own domain-specific language that cannot call arbitrary PHP functions, only the ones you provide.

Comment: I had not thought about using phar archives, it looks like a good solution for the type of distribution I want. The twig example I though about something similar, a custom file extension that the core reads/executes or something like that.